# Binding ng-show into custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In a `<table>` header where labels can be clicked to order data in some specific way, I'm trying to replace this code :

```
<th>
  <a class="sortable-th" href="#" data-ng-click="sortType = 'atSenderScheduledDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
    Date
    <span data-ng-show="sortType == 'atSenderScheduledDate' && !sortReverse" class="md-chevron-down"></span>
    <span data-ng-show="sortType == 'atSenderScheduledDate' && sortReverse" class="md-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
</th>
```

(where only one `<span>` is displayed to show the sorting order) with a custom directive such as :

```
<th>
  <th-sortable type="atSenderScheduledDate" label="Date"></th-sortable>
</th>
```

The Controller holds the sorting variables :

```
$scope.sortType = 'atSenderScheduledDate'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse = false;  // set the default sort order
```

And the directive is as follows :

```
(function() {

  angular.module('app').directive('thSortable', thSortable);

  thSortable.$inject = ['$parse'];

  function thSortable($parse) {
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      scope : {
      },
      link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var type = attrs.type;
        var label = attrs.label;

        var newElem = '';
        newElem += '<a class="sortable-th" href="#">';
        newElem += '  ' + label;
        newElem += '  <span class="md-chevron-up" data-ng-show="sortType === \'' + type + '\' && !sortReverse"></span>';
        newElem += '  <span class="md-chevron-down" data-ng-show="sortType === \'' + type + '\' && sortReverse"></span>';
        newElem += '</a>';
        elem.append(newElem);

        elem.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            $parse("sortType").assign(scope.$parent, type);
            $parse("sortReverse").assign(scope.$parent, !scope.$parent.sortReverse);
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

The `click` binding is working as expected and the data is accurately being ordered. However, I can't manage to get the `data-ng-show` part of the two `<span>`'s working, in order to only display the relevant one.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.bind('click', function() {
   scope.$apply(function() {
     $parse("sortType").assign(scope.$parent, type);
     $parse("sortReverse").assign(scope.$parent, !scope.$parent.sortReverse);
   });
});
```

You are using `$parse("sortType")` and `$parse("sortReverse")`, not sure how would it update your `parent scope properties`. Since your directive is an isolate scope, why don't you pull them in your scope like below and use it.

```
 scope : {
     sortType: "=",
     sortReverse: "="
 },
```

Then in your link function you can use `scope.sortType` and `scope.sortReverse` and also its much better to send `object` to `ng-model` as `boolean` values would create a whole `new scope inside your directive.`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I think that the parent scope is updated succesfully as the sort is performing as expected. What I'm missing, I guess, is the right syntax for the

`newElem += '  <span class="md-chevron-up" data-ng-show="sortType === \'' + type + '\' && !sortReverse"></span>';` part of the directive.